# How to call a curried function on a mock?

Tags: scala, testing, mocking, mockito

I have a generic function that looks like so

```
  def getFromCacheOrCallService[T: ClassTag](cacheKey: String, duration: Duration = cacheDefaultDuration)(
      callServiceToFetchValue: => Try[T]
  ): Try[T]
```

and Im trying to figure out how to mock this function in a way that will always call `callServiceToFetchValue` and use it instead. I have this so far

```
doAnswer(invocation => {
  invocation.getArgumentAt(1, classOf[() => Try[marketplace]])()
}).when(marketplaceCache).cacheable(any(), any())(any())(any())
```

Which if I understand what Im doing correctly should call the function passed, but whenever I try to run I get this error

```
Invalid use of argument matchers!
4 matchers expected, 3 recorded:
```

Why is it saying it expects 4 matchers? I have 4 matchers, I dont understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the curried function that's the problem, it's the pass-by-name parameter.
Mockito doesn't support it very well, and I am not aware of any good workarounds aside from actually declaring that parameter as an actual function `() => Try[T]`
(or, perhaps, `String => Try[T]` - it actually looks a bit weird without the key being passed it).

Comment: Oh well thats a bummer to hear, is there at least a way to put in the matchers to have them work? Im still lost on why it says theres only 3 when there are 4 of them

Comment: @DavidWolak like I said, not that I know of :(

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who ran into a similiar problem the solution I ended up with was changing the defintion of `getFromCacheOrCallService` to

```
  def getFromCacheOrCallService[T: ClassTag](cacheKey: String, duration: Duration = cacheDefaultDuration)(
      callServiceToFetchValue:() => Try[T]
  ): Try[T]
```

And then it worked. However since most of the time I was passing in functions like

```
 def getFromCacheOrCallService("key", Duration(10, MINUTES)(callServiceToFetchValue(SomeInput))
```

I had to change it to

```
 def getFromCacheOrCallService("key", Duration(10, MINUTES)({ () => callServiceToFetchValue(SomeInput)} )
```